# how to set text alignment of dynamically added label

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2005, text-alignment

how to set text  alignment  of dynamically added label 
where i am getting name of label in string variable
one label is dynamically added in panel

```
  Dim instance As New Label
  Dim stringVariable As String
```

on form load event ::

```
    instance.Location = New Point(15, 15)
    instance.Size = New Size(60, 30)
    instance.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.FixedSingle
    instance.AutoSize = False
    instance.Text = "LABEL1"
    Me.Panel1.Controls.Add(instance)
```

i am getting name by:

```
    for each c as control in Panel1.Controls
    stringVariable=c.name
    next
```

but its not possible to

```
   Me.Panel1.Controls(stringVariable).textalign ??????
   it does not show text align property
```

please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DirectCast(Me.Panel1.Controls("Label1"), Label).TextAlign = ContentAlignment.TopRight
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that these values will set TextAlign

```
Public pTop_Center As Long = 2
Public pMiddle_Center As Long = 32
Public pBotton_Center = 512

 btn.TextAlign = pBotton_Center
```

Comment: this question has already an accepted answer and your answer doesn't add new information